# Node.js Web Scraping with Jsdom

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, jsdom

I would like to scrape the http://www.euromillones.com.es/ website to get the last winning 5 numbers and two stars. It can be seen on the left column of the website. I've been reading tutorials, but I am not capable of achieving this.

This is the code I wrote so far:

```
app.get('/winnernumbers', function(req, res){
    //Tell the request that we want to fetch youtube.com, send the results to a callback function
        request({uri: 'http://www.euromillones.com.es/ '}, function(err, response, body){
                var self = this;
        self.items = new Array();//I feel like I want to save my results in an array

        //Just a basic error check
                if(err && response.statusCode !== 200){console.log('Request error.');}
                //Send the body param as the HTML code we will parse in jsdom
        //also tell jsdom to attach jQuery in the scripts and loaded from jQuery.com
        jsdom.env({
                        html: body,
                        scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js ']
                }, function(err, window){
            //Use jQuery just as in a regular HTML page
                        var $ = window.jQuery;

                        res.send($('title').text());
                });
        });
});
```

I am getting the following error:

Must pass a "created", "loaded", "done" option or a callback to jsdom.env.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me that you've just used a combination of arguments that jsdom does not know how to handle. The [documentation](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#how-it-works) shows this signature:

```
jsdom.env(string, [scripts], [config], callback);
```

The two middle arguments are optional but you'll note that all possible combinations here start with a string and end with a callback. The documentation mentions one more way to call `jsdom.env`, and that's by passing a single `config` argument. What you are doing amounts to:

```
jsdom.env(config, callback);
```

which does not correspond to any of the documented methods. I would suggest changing your code to pass a single config argument. You can move your current callback to the `done` field of that config object. Something like this:

```
jsdom.env({
    html: body,
    scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js'],
    done: function (err, window) {
        //Use jQuery just as in a regular HTML page
        var $ = window.jQuery;
        res.send($('title').text());
    }
});
```

Comment: this is how i solved it:

jsdom.env({
    url: "http://www.euromillones.com.es/",
    scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js'],
    done: function (err, window) {
        //Use jQuery just as in a regular HTML page
        var $ = window.jQuery;
        res.send($('title').text());
    }
    });

Comment: 2018 called and said: "jsdom.env is undefined"